# How to get the caller winform

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a winform that opens (ShowDialog) other winforms.

Is there a way to get the first winform from the opened winform without passing it as a parameter or using a "public static" solution ?

EDIT: Didn't notice that i'm in a user control, how can i get my form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.FindForm() will get the form that hosts your custom control. Once you get the form, you can use .Owner property.

IMHO.

Comment: I think FindForm returns the form only if we did .Controls.Add but here we just created a form and opened it.

Comment: If so, try iterate .Parent property until you find the first Form object in the chain of parents. 
P.S. It's quite strange that FindForm() returns null...

Comment: I meant to say "created UserControl".

Comment: If you didn't place the user control to any container then you have no relation to the form.

Answer (score 0):

What about the Owner property of a form ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I came up with was to hook the Paint event in your UserControl.  I know, this is bad practice, but it works.  I am not proud...:)

```
    private bool _uglyOnlyDoSomethingFirstTimeInPaintEventFlag = false;
    private void btnDestination_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_uglyOnlyDoSomethingFirstTimeInPaintEventFlag)
        {
            _uglyOnlyDoSomethingFirstTimeInPaintEventFlag = true;
            //...do FindForm() here and you should get the right form
        }
    }
```